# Where are these names/mappings coming from?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I'm running through the [ASP.Net Web API getting started tutorial](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) on the ASP.Net site.

I've coded up the example and I understand everything I have done. I'm very experienced with C#, but have never touched any ASP.Net before.

In the example, we create a `Product` class and a `ProductsController : ApiController` class. That's all fine.

When I navigate to `/api/products`, it lists the products defined, and when I navigate to `/api/products/id`, it lists the product with that ID.

Where is all this coming from? The class is called `Product` and one called `ProductsController`, so I don't know where "product**s**" is coming from. Moreover, I tried renaming `GetAllProducts()` and `GetProduct(int)` to something random and *it still works*.

So what is going on here? As someone coming from Desktop C# development, I cannot see where the connection is between these things, and I cannot see how I can make my own API such as `/api/foo/bar` that does something arbitrary.

Comment: When web api receives a web requests, it routes to one of your controller methods by convension: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebAPI supports a predefined set of naming conventions to determine the correct controller to route the request to.

Firstly, take the default route configuration:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

WebAPI will perform the following steps to try and determine which action to execute:

- To find the controller, Web API adds `Controller` to the value of the `{controller}` variable (i.e. turning `products` into `ProductsController`).
- To find the action, Web API looks at the HTTP method, and then looks for an action whose name begins with that HTTP method name. For example, with a GET request, Web API looks for an action that starts with `Get...`, such as `GetProduct` or `GetAllProducts`.  This convention applies only to GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE methods.
- Other placeholder variables in the route template, such as `{id}`, are mapped to action parameters.

You can find more info here: [Routing in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: Ok, I understand. I renamed `ProductsController` to `DuctsprodController` and now I can access them through `/api/ductsprod`. This is all highly strange compared with regular desktop C# programming. Never have I seen a case where function/class substrings are used, or where the system "looks for an action whose name begins with [...]". Also, `ProductsController` is not static, and I can't see it being instantiated anywhere, so where does the object come from? I presume the CLR just creates one when the browser navigates to `/api/products`?

Comment: HTTP is stateless, so a new instance of the controller is instantiated by the WebAPI framework for every request.

Answer (score 1):

Because the naming conversion creates routes for you. Your `ProductsController` class gives the `/products` part and your `GetAllProducts` gives the HTTP method `GET`, so the request `/api/products` hits the corresponding method. It's still working even you rename `GetAllProducts` to `Get123`, because web-api only cares the `Get` keyword and it has no parameters.

`GetProduct(int id)` is the same, the only difference is it has a parameter. That's why it's hit by `/api/products/1`. The web-api chooses it as a best match (via reflection) to the request url. Similarly it's still working if you rename it to `Get123(int id)`.

The above are default naming conversion routes. You can always modify them by [RouteAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.routeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx).